# What is the difference between MERGE and UNION ALL assuming that inputs to the transformation are sorted?

Tags: ssis

MERGE requires both the inputs to be sorted and returns the output in sorted order.

Where as UNION ALL doesn't require inputs to be sorted and doesn't order the output.

But if we apply SORT to sort the inputs of the UNION ALL, then what is the difference between MERGE and UNION ALL?

Comment: The key here is that SORT is an expensive blocking operation. But yes the doco is very unclear. I imagine that if your data is already ordered and you require it to remain ordered for downstream activities, you should use MERGE, whereas if you don't require sorting use `UNION ALL` Personally I never use these transformations I always use SQL

Comment: I think even if the data is sorted, with UNION all the end result will be 2 separate sorted data unioned. Whereas with merge the entire output would be sorted?